# How to sum series of datetimes

Tags: mysql, datetime, datediff

DATABASE Looks like this... I need to find the total time spent by projID!

three columns:

projectID, datetimeStart, datetimeEnd

multiple entries say for a single project... could contain a number of rows with datetimeStart and datetimeEnd.

I need to find and sum total number of seconds ( to keep this simple ) for a project.

Comment: What is the column for `datetimeStart` and `datetimeEnd` ? Perhaps start with the [Mysql Documenation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for date and time functions, see if you can work this one through, otherwise, I'll see if I can help. Perhaps post a SQLFiddle with your database and a couple of dummy rows, as well as what you expect the final results to be?

Comment: column type for datetimeStart and datetimeEnd - is datetime.

Comment: Can you edit your post with some example data you may have so that we can more clearly see what you're expecting this query to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding what you want correctly, I am assuming that `projectID` isn't a unique value in this table as it is a foreign key. With that in mind, then you should be able to do something like this in order to get your desired result.

```
SELECT projectID, 
       SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, datetimeStart, datetimeEnd)) 
       as difference_in_minutes 
FROM projects 
GROUP BY productID;
```

Comment: Cheers this was perfect.